# Firebase Admin 6.2.0 upgrade issue: server can't access Realtime Database

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-admin, google-cloud-endpoints-v2

I've recently upgraded my Google Cloud Endpoints server from Firebase Admin 4.1.2 to 6.2.0. After the upgrade, however, the server does not seem to be able to access my Firebase Realtime Database in the way that it could before the upgrade.

The only code I've changed, apart from the Gradle file where I specify Firebase Admin 6.2.0 instead of 4.1.2, is in this initialization block:

```
static {

    FirebaseOptions options = null;
    FileInputStream serviceAccount =
            null;
    try {
        serviceAccount = new FileInputStream(new File("WEB-INF/path_to_file.json"));
        options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
                //.setCredential(FirebaseCredentials.fromCertificate(serviceAccount)) OLD VERSION
                .setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.fromStream(serviceAccount)) // NEW VERSION
                .setDatabaseUrl(FIREBASE_NAME)
                .build();
        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.warning(e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The only line that has changed here is the `setCredentials()` line.

My current hypothesis is that the problem is some kind authentication issue. But presumably there can't be anything wrong with the service account key in the json file, otherwise the old version of the server would also have the same problem. Has anyone encountered this kind of issue before? Any theories as to what the source of problem might be?

UPDATE: I've tried playing around with the initialization block, seeing what happens if I comment out the `setCredentials()` line, or give the wrong path to the `FileInputStream`, or pass the wrong url to `setDatabaseUrl()`. In all of those cases, I log some kind of error which indicates that the initialization has failed. With the code as it is above, however, I do not log any error. So the problem remains a mystery.

The test code I'm using to try to access my Realtime Database is very simple:

```
    final FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    final DatabaseReference ref = database.getReferenceFromUrl(FIREBASE_NAME);

    Map<String, Object> testMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    testMap.put("test", "test");

    ref.child("server_test").updateChildrenAsync(testMap);
```

Nothing gets written, however.

Comment: As far as I know, the `initializeApp` method no longer accepts a parameter. When upgrading, did you follow their guide on the breaking changes?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but `FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options)` seems to be correct, as indicated by the code snippet here:(https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup)

Comment: Oh, I figured you were using the 1.0 version of the SDK. Got my info from here: (https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta-v1-diff)

Comment: Just to clarify: my issue concerns a Google Cloud Endpoints server written in Java code; it's not Firebase Cloud Functions JS code.

Answer (score 2):

By a process of elimination, I eventually managed to track the source of the problem down to my `appengine-web.xml` file. That file contained one line which needed to be changed in order for the upgraded server to work properly:

Before: `<url-stream-handler>urlfetch</url-stream-handler>`

After:  `<url-stream-handler>native</url-stream-handler>`

If anyone faces a similar problem, I hope this might prove useful.